# Show 'full size' of a window control

Tags: c++, mfc, c++17

I have a bit of an issue that involves a [`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class?view=vs-2019).

Normally you assign a window size to it and if it cannot fit it sets up a vertical scroll bar (for all I can see this is just the normal generic `CWnd` associated scrollbar). And this is great for when you just want to dump the control inside a re-sizeable window.

However, I have the reverse situation, where I would like to fit my outer window so that it shows the entire height of the control (such that no scroll bar needs to be created). In order to do that I somehow needs to get an **ideal height** given the contents of the control. Is that possible in some generic way or just for `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` ?

---

To give a little more background, I have multiple gridctrl's on top of each other so to speak. Therefore, I have put a scrollbar on the outer window so you could say they share that scrollbar (and this one is working just fine). I could go into details why I want this design(as opposed to just one gridctrl with everything), but basicly it's a kind of cards where each card/element has it's own set of properties.

Comment: Does inflating [GetListRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class#getlistrect) by [GetHeaderHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class#getheaderheight) and [GetDescriptionHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertygridctrl-class#getdescriptionheight) produce the desired rectangle size? If so, you can pass this into [CalcWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#calcwindowrect) to get your final window size.

Comment: @IInspectable good comment, although I suspect/it seems GetListRect just gives the actual size hence its not particularly helpfull (in my case theres no description area and header so that simplifies it somewhat)